# A clock with a microsecond timer

Tags: python, time

I'm trying to create a microsecond timer on python. The goal is to have a "tick" every microsecond.

My current approach was:

```
us = list()
while len(us) <= 1000:
    t = time.time()*1000000
    if t.is_integer():
        us.append(t)
```

It shows that there are clear limitations in term of timing that I am not aware of.

The 656 first values were `1532960518213592.0`. The while loop executes in the "same" microsecond.
Then the value jumps to `1532960518217613.0`. The maximum resolution seems to be 4021 us.

How can I overcome those limitations?

**EDIT: About this measurements.**

Chrome with a youtube video was running in the background. + Outlooks, Teams, Adobe and some other stuff.
The CPU is an i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20 GHz (2 cores).

Comment: Is it possible that your computer simply runs fast enough that the first 656 executions *were* executed in the same microsecond, and then a context-switch to a different process accounts for the gap?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Meaning that the 656 first executions are executed in the same us, then the CPU scheduling switch to Chrome, Outlook, or whatever else was running the background, and then reswitch to the python interpreter 4021 us later to end the while loop? Well maybe, anyway, how can I overcome this? ^^

Comment: Try it with `time.clock` instead of `time.time`. [A brief description of the differences](https://www.pythoncentral.io/measure-time-in-python-time-time-vs-time-clock/)

Comment: @shmee Aside that I do not like the fact that it counts the time from the first call, it is worst. The resolution is fixed but of 40 000 us between 2 elements in my list `us`.

Comment: There are inherent limitations. Can you achieve what you need by checking the time and adjusting on the fly, or do you need the code to execute in true timing? For the latter, you probably need specialized hardware - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing

Comment: @Mathieu what about `time.perf_counter()`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter

Comment: @KennyOstrom My final goal is to emulate a piece of hardware. That hardware has a microcontroller running up to a few MHz and no floating point module. A microsecond timer is implemented on it. I'm currently trying to emulate that timer on which the rest of the operation performed by the MCU will be based.

Comment: @KennyOstrom My final resort will be to use a fator of 1 000 or more between the timer of the MCU and the emulated version, but that's more a final resort making everything more complicated, and human errors more likely.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Same as `time.clock()`.

Comment: If you're simulating a hardware timer, in software, you can't really expect it to be true. However, you do have a clock you can rely on when you read it. If the long-term average is all that really matters, you can just have a lower resolution timer, and run off the microseconds which should have passed. It should average out the same over longer time periods, and it should be good enough that a human can't really tell the difference.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Yes for the first part. The hardware has a clock rate far lower than the one from my computer. Thus, a timer implemented on that external hardware should be implementable on a PC. The long-term is not what matters, I need those timing because at some of them, operations will be scheduled (messages send to an SPI). Those operations have a fix duration (10,  20 us) and I will have a look at how the sequence on the SPI (Serial Peripheral Interface) would look like, and what will be the limitations implied on my system.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the current time is functionality provided by your operating system, so it will have different behaviors on different systems, both in terms of precision of the clock and in terms of how often it is polled.  Also keep in mind that your program can be paused an resumed in it's execution by the scheduler of your operating system.

Here is a simplified version of your code:

```
[time.time() * 10**6 for i in range(1000)]
```

On my local computer (Windows Ubuntu Subsystem), this produces the following (notice it's about one per second with gaps):

> [1532961190053186.0,
>    1532961190053189.0,
>    1532961190053190.0,
>    1532961190053191.0,
>    1532961190053192.0,
>    1532961190053193.0,
>    1532961190053194.0,
>    1532961190053195.0,
>    1532961190053196.0,
>    1532961190053198.0, ...]

On a server (Ubuntu), this produces the following (notice the same time occurring multiple times):

> [1532961559708196.0,
>    1532961559708198.0,
>    1532961559708199.0,
>    1532961559708199.0,
>    1532961559708199.0,
>    1532961559708200.0,
>    1532961559708200.0,
>    1532961559708200.0,
>    1532961559708200.0,
>    1532961559708201.0, ...]

Comment: Yes that I am fully aware of. However, from my understanding, a clock should be limited by the CPU clock rate. With a CPU running at several GHz (max 2200000000.0 ticks per second in my case), can't we simply select the one relevant (1000000 needed in my case)? I know that by passing the scheduler is not possible, but still, isn't there a way to produce a high resolution timer on a pc?

Comment: Try running the code in my answer on your computer.  If you are still getting gaps of milliseconds, the it's a limitation of the system you're running on, not of python

Comment: Your code is giving me this unique value in the list: `1532962649691606.8`. Moreover, it does not keep integers value, i.e. round us timings. If it would have switch from one value to the next, the decimal value might have changed.

Comment: Like in this second runs where the 2 values presents are: `1532962720779231.5` and `1532962720779732.2`, separated by 500.75 us.

Comment: It's pretty easy to add code to remove the decimal components or duplicate values, but it looks like your system library is caching the time values that are being passed to Python.   My best advice is to try it on a different computer.  You can get a free tier virtual server on AWS for 12 months

Comment: ... Other computer (Windows - Intel Xeon CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10 GHz - 8 Cores): Unique value: `1532963221888327.8`.

Comment: Try using Ubuntu.  This may be a Windows problem